# Is there any drawback to MongoDb data being on on Amazon EFS?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I have a relatively low traffic system, but I want to keep the data safe. The data are stored in a single MongoDb instance. I don't want to run multiple replicas and manage them. So, I'm planning to change the data directory to EFS path to take advantage of its replication and other benefits. Periodic snapshots can cause data loss, and recovery is manual.

Is there any drawback of storing the data and the journal files on EFS caused by the additional latency?

Comment: To clarify... are you planning to access this data exclusively through a single MongoDB installation that is running on a single EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, for at least a few more months. There are hardly 200 writes per day. Does this help simplify the setup?

Comment: Yes. I think @jbird got the same initial impression that I did, that you were imagining multiple EC2 machines running MongoDB componentry and sharing a single backing store that lived in EFS, in which case he/she is totally correct, that's a no-go.  But if you're just looking for the storage resiliency aspect, it's a bit of an unconventional use case... but I'd say "try it and see what you think."  What will it hurt to try?  Stop the service, copy the files, configure paths, restart. I see no intrinsic reason why it shouldn't work reasonably well at low traffic volumes like you describe.

Comment: Thanks. I see this comment on MongoDb documentatio.   "If you decide to use NFS, add the following NFS options to your /etc/fstab file: bg, nolock, and noatime.  "    https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#remote-filesystems

Comment: I'd love to hear a follow up to this. I'm considering a similar solution for a very small, single instance mongo deployment to support a CMS website.

Answer (score 3):

As you alluded to, EFS objects are [replicated](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/faq/) across availability zones. To contrast, EBS volumes are only [replicated](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) within a single availability zone. The difference in pricing is significant with EFS currently starting at $0.30/GB and EBS starting at $0.10/GB. Typical EFS use-cases are for data that needs to be shared across instances, like user home directories and application data. EBS is also capable of providing the lowest-latency.

With those points in mind, I do not recommend EFS for MongoDB data. If EFS's multi-AZ replication is your major desire, you could achieve it with EBS by taking periodic snapshots (which are stored in S3) of the EBS volume. I think EBS will give you better performance and lower cost.

Using EFS is not really an alternative to running multiple MongoDB instances. Replication and sharding are not things that EFS can help achieve.

Comment: Periodic snapshots are not sufficient. That could cause data loss. Also the recovery is manual. Besides, my data size is still small hardly 1gb, and I don't see it increase beyond 5gb in the near future. So storage cost is not a major issue in my case.

Comment: An EBS snapshot is a point-in-time backup. Should something go wrong you have a point to revert to. With EFS you don't have that -- if you experience data loss for whatever reason you have no backup (without some custom script).

Comment: I've seen a situation when EBS snapshot was unusable because of failure of EBS. Sounds weird? Yes. But that's what happened in reality. Be prepared

Comment: What about AWS Backup, doesn't it solve the timed snapshots problem? Also, as I understood EFS could be perfect for him at the time. I'd also go for it personally. Low cost, because there is no data. No need to think about scalability if there will be more data. And also replicas across regions. The major reason however for the big Go is the straightforward setup and almost no mess. I'd pay the extra 5 dollars just for the ease of setup and the scalability. IF indeed this Amazon Backup is indeed as truely OK like EBS Snapshots.